# String Interpolation with Text View and Textfield in Swiftui

Tags: swiftui

Hi I'm wondering if there's any way to have string interpolation with a textfield and Text in Swiftui. Like

```
Text("hi \(TextField("Enter your name", $name)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do that you can put your statements in an Hstack like so:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var name = ""
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hi")
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
                .frame(width: (name.isEmpty ? 45 : 0) + CGFloat(name.count) * 9)
            Text("blabla")
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This gives you a dynamic change, but not a perfect one Because the size of each character is different you will get a bigger whitespace at the end. I just choose 9 here, for char width. I still think having a extra Textfield and using the variable then later, is the better option.

Comment: Hi, This is my current solution but I wanted to have the textfield size change according to the text inside the textfield. Currently the size of the textfield remains as the same size as the placeholder text rather than dynamically changing

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
            Text("Hi \(name)")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you want 
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you. Is there anyway to have user type in the name right next to the hi rather than above?